# Git credential helper over OpenSSH from Windows server

Tags: windows, windows-10, git, openssh

I have a Windows 10 machine with an OpenSSH server.
My goal is to remotely connect to it and clone some repositories that need authentication over HTTPS.

I keep getting this error:

```
Checking out https://username@mydomain.com/myrepo.git (integration/master) as myrepo

Logon failed, use ctrl+c to cancel basic credential prompt.
bash: /dev/tty: No such device or address
error: failed to execute prompt script (exit code 1)
fatal: could not read Password for 'https://username@mydomain.com/': No error
```

I researched a bit and all solutions I found were related to setting credential.helper as wincred, which is not a viable solution in my case since I don´t have GUI access.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to be prompted for a passphrase with Git, then you need to use some sort of credential helper.  Git ships with one called `store` which stores the credentials in a file in your home directory.  This is not very secure, but if you don't have any other options, it's a possibility.  You can run `git credential-store --help` for more information on it.

It's also possible to use a URL-encoded password in the URL, but this is even less secure, since it could be printed to the terminal.